# Installing TensorFlow from Sources, on windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10, avx, sse4

I have already installed tensorflow-gpu, and it is working fine.

I now want to install tensorflow-gpu from source to take advantage of AVX and SSE4.2-1.0 instruction set, given my system configuration below;

1. CPU : Dual Intel Xeon E5 2670, Sandy Bridge-EP/EX,Revision C2,Instructions MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, Intel 64, NX, VMX, AES, AVX
2. GPU : EVGA SC NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB
3. Motherboard: Tyan S7066WGM3NR , version R1.0
4. RAM : 32 GB octa-channel DDR3 666 MHz
5. OS : Windows 10 Pro 64 bit

The tensorflow website (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources), video on youtube and the other questions on stackoverflow are more linux oriented, and even then, not straight forward for newbies like myself.

Could anyone please guide me through the process of installing tensorflow-gpu from source, on windows 10 ?

Please feel free to ask for additional system information, or similar.

thank you.

Comment: HI. I forgot to mention that I am using Python 3.5. Also, I would appreciate if the guide could be in a check list manner. thanks

Comment: There is a step-by-step guide to building on Windows here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your best bet is to use the CMake configuration that you can find [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/README.md). Note that it is rather experimental, and completing the compilation, as well as [linking with the library](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7258), may require the occasional hack.